# Problem echoing php string as javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, wordpress

I'm using Jaipho to display images to a mobile gallery from a custom Wordpress plugin. The wordpress theme that uses the Jaipho gallery is displayed using the WP-mobile-detector plugin.

The problem I am having is when I use php to gather the URLs to the photos to echo out a function to be parsed by javascript. I took the resulting static javascript code from the element inspector of Safari and pasted it into my code, commenting out the php, and it works everywhere. Safari for iOS doesn't seem to like the javascript code generated by the php.

- HTML 5

  - `<DOCTYPE html>`
  - `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>`
  - `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>`
- PHP 5.2.6
- Wordpress 3.2.1

When it works:

- User Agent set to iPhone on Safari
- Static code replaces php-generated code

  ```
  $imageArray = $case->images_assc_array();  
  $i = 0;  
  foreach($imageArray['views'] as $view_name => $view_images) {  
     $before_img = $view_images['before'];  
     $after_img = $view_images['after'];  

     echo "dao.ReadImage($i,'".$before_img->medium_size()."','".$before_img->small_size()."','".ucfirst($view_name)." Before','".$case->description."');";  
     $i++;  
     echo "dao.ReadImage($i,'".$after_img->medium_size()."','".$after_img->small_size()."','".ucfirst($view_name)." After','".$case->description."');";  
     $i++;  
  }
  ```

Expected example generated output:

```
    dao.ReadImage( 0,'/wp-content/uploads/rmgallery_images/medium/408/before-front.jpg','/wp-content/uploads/rmgallery_images/small/408/before-front.jpg','Front Before','38 year old who underwent a tummy tuck.');  
    dao.ReadImage( 1,'/wp-content/uploads/rmgallery_images/medium/410/after-front.jpg','/wp-content/uploads/rmgallery_images/small/410/after-front.jpg','Front After','38 year old who underwent a tummy tuck.');
    dao.ReadImage( 2,'/wp-content/uploads/rmgallery_images/medium/409/before-side.jpg','/wp-content/uploads/rmgallery_images/small/409/before-side.jpg','Side Before','38 year old who underwent a tummy tuck.');
    dao.ReadImage( 3,'/wp-content/uploads/rmgallery_images/medium/411/after-side.jpg','/wp-content/uploads/rmgallery_images/small/411/after-side.jpg','Side After','38 year old who underwent a tummy tuck.');
```

Comment: Any javascript errors occurring?

Comment: What does the PHP log tell you? does it output any error? if not, does it output any js errors?

Comment: @Jrod iOS Console Javascript errors:  
`SyntaxError: Parse error on line 224` which is `var dao = new Jph_Dao();`, the line right before my php.

Comment: @jackJoe No errors in the log

Comment: Never directly output data from PHP into javascript literals - it's far too easy to introduce syntaxe errors which will utterly kill your javascript. Always pass your data through json_encode() first, so you always produce syntactically valid JS code.

Comment: @Marc B I'll give it a try, however the exact same code works on two other domains hosted on the same server which is why I figured it should work.

Comment: @Jrod - I forgot to include in the other comment the `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: init_jaipho` error on line 79, which is a function that runs at onLoad that references the `Jph_Dao()` function right after the php code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to @Marc B and @linuxrules94 for a combined solution:

```
<?php
$imageArray = $case->images_assc_array();
$i = 0;

    foreach($imageArray['views'] as $view_name => $view_images):
        $before_img = $view_images['before'];
        $after_img = $view_images['after'];
    ?>

        dao.ReadImage(<?=json_encode($i);?>, <?=json_encode($before_img->medium_size());?>,<?=json_encode($before_img->small_size());?>,<?=json_encode(ucfirst($view_name));?> + " Before", <?=json_encode(stripslashes($case->description));?>);
        <? $i++; ?>
        dao.ReadImage(<?=json_encode($i);?>, <?=json_encode($after_img->medium_size());?>,<?=json_encode($after_img->small_size());?>,<?=json_encode(ucfirst($view_name));?> + " After", <?=json_encode(stripslashes($case->description));?>);
        <? $i++;
    endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You have some mismatched quotes:

`echo dao.ReadImage($i,'".$before...`

`echo "dao.ReadImage($i,'".$after...`

and so on.

Try these:

```
echo 'dao.ReadImage('.$i.',"'.$before_img->medium_size().'","'.$before_img->small_size().'","'.ucfirst($view_name).' Before","'.$case->description.'");';
echo 'dao.ReadImage('.$i.',"'.$after_img->medium_size().'","'.$after_img->small_size().'","'.ucfirst($view_name).' After","'.$case->description.'");';
```

Comment: That was just a typo from my debugging. The quotes aren't the issue, but good eyes

Answer (score 1):

How about using heredocs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: I tried that with no luck. It seems to be a parsing issue between php and javascript.

(Also, the code was in a list I thought had ended. 8 spaces fixed it).

Comment: @cfree How about using heredocs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php or do what marc B said

Comment: @cfree Cool you made a combined solution from Marc B and me :D